# Select2 : updateSelection runned twice

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-select2, ui-select2

I use Select2 jQuery plugin with angular-ui-select2 (select2 integration via angularjs directive).

I put the directive in the right place, in the select tag :

```
<select ng-model="formation.formationRemplacementTemp.formation.id" ng-options="f.id as (f | formationName) for f in formations" ui-select2="select2Formations">
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

When I select an option, the placeholder isn't filled. By debugging the `updateSelection` function of the select2 plugin, I saw that it is runned twice : the first time it fills the placeholder (the `data` object isn't null) but the second time it empties the placeholder (`data` is null).

Why is this function reached twice and how to avoid this ?